# I get sometimes TOKEN_EXPIRED sometimes when using Method: accounts.signInWithPassword. How do I fix this?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, error-code

Basically I am using firebase auth with google cloud identity platform and sometimes I can log in properly in my program with no problem and some other times it just retrieves an error saying TOKEN_EXPIRED even though I don't need an idToken for logging in, isn't the point of logging in to retrieve the idToken, how am I supposed to get the idToken if not even signed in? Or how do I avoid this at all.

I do notice how closing down the program and reopening it will fix the problem but in my program I want to use a save and load feature so everytime you start the program up it will load from last save, (which happens every 10 seconds) which means if I load from save the TOKEN_EXPIRED error is still there which means it will be there for eternity. Or is this a waiting game, where you have to wait a couple of minutes to make another request?

Comment: Please edit the question to share the code and instructions we can use to duplicate the behavior you're observing.  Without that, we're not likely to be of much help.

Comment: Authorization tokens can expire or be revoked. You must write code to handle that situation. Review Doug's comment and add the required details to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, from previous actions, there was an idToken key that was still there when logging in which I guess messed it up, all I had to do was delete the idToken key everytime I try to log in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).